# Multiple interviews and reimbursement from the same institution

Tags: postdocs, interview, travel

I have two related questions. Here's the situation: I have 3 postdoc interviews at the same university and I scheduled them within the same week for obvious travel reasons.

Question 1: should I mention to all parties that I will be doing other interviews at the university? I only ask because two are in the same department, so it would be awkward if I crossed paths with one while being given a tour by the other. And should I take one of the positions, I would no doubt encounter the others later.

Question 2: I am offered reimbursement for travel by one of the interviewers. I did not ask for reimbursement for the two others nor did they offer (yet). I am not traveling exclusively for the lab offering reimbursement, so is it appropriate to accept?

Question 2A: If I do accept, and another group offers reimbursement, can I recommend that the costs be split somehow? There's no reason for one group in particular to pay for everything.

Comment: What field is this? This situation is entirely alien to me. But I imagine that, unless there is bad politics between the groups, this is a good situation and not something to be hidden.

Answer (score 3):

It does sound to me like you should disclose that you are doing other interviews at that campus, particularly since they are likely to notice you back in the same building later in the week and wonder why you are there.  And, the department offering to pay your travel is probably going to wonder why you are spending the whole week there when your interview is just one day.  Finally, I imagine them knowing you're being courted by multiple departments might make you seem like a more attractive candidate.